# Робокасса, result.php, отправка e-mail

Tags: php

Для моего сайта я настроил все, кроме result.php, на который отправляется запрос после успешной оплаты. В стандартном скрипте result.php, который можно скачать на сайте робокассы, все данные (которые пользователь до оплаты вводил в форму) копируются в txt файл, а мне нужно, чтобы они отправлялись на два email'а — админу, и покупателю. В хостинге reg ru я создал почтовый домен, и ящик. Получившийся ящик вставил в функцию "mail()" в файле result.php, для отправки письма админу после успешной оплаты, а во вторую функцию "mail()" вставил введенный пользователем e-mail(из переменной). Далее попробовал оплатить - ни на один e-mail письмо не приходит. Что я делаю не так? Заранее большое спасибо за любую помощь!

p.s. тариф в рег ру у меня поддерживает и e-mail, и php и тд.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте

Вам не нужно использовать 2 функции [mail()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php), достаточно использовать один раз, но написать 2 получателя:

```
$to= "mary@example.com" . ", " ; //обратите внимание на запятую
$to .= "kelly@example.com"; // второй получатель
$subject = "My Subject"; // заголовок письма
$message = "My Message"; // текст письма

// Заголовки сугубо для примера, прочтите о них
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Затрудняюсь сказать в чем  Ваша ошибка не видя код.

Comment: @десиптикон2005рус, тогда использование 2х mail() действительно оправдано, а я неправильно понял вопрос.  

Если с отправкой все еще проблемы, то стоит сделать проверку. 
Если mail() возвращает True, значит письмо отправлено и проблема в чем-то другом. Можно проверить простым if'ом